# Visual Studio 2017 ignoring source maps when debugging under cscript.exe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, wsh

I have the following files in a folder:

```
loader.js
loader.js.map
loader.ts
tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "target":"es3",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

The generated map file (`loader.js.map`) looks like this:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "loader.js",
    "sourceRoot": "",
    "sources": ["loader.ts"],
    "names": [],
    "mappings": ";AAAA,IAAM,iBAAiB,GAAG,UAAI,GAA0B;IACpD,IAAM,OAAO,GAAQ,EAAE,CAAC;IACxB,IAAM,UAAU,GAAG,IAAI,UAAU,CAAI,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;IAC1C,UAAU,CAAC,SAAS,EAAE,CAAC;IACvB,OAAO,CAAC,UAAU,CAAC,KAAK,EAAE,EAAE,CAAC;QACzB,OAAO,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,UAAU,CAAC,IAAI,EAAE,CAAC,CAAC;QAChC,UAAU,CAAC,QAAQ,EAAE,CAAC;IAC1B,CAAC;IACD,MAAM,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC;AACnB,CAAC,CAAC;AAEF,IAAM,GAAG,GAAG,IAAI,aAAa,CAAC,4BAA4B,CAAC,CAAC;AAC5D,IAAM,KAAK,GAAG,IAAI,aAAa,CAAC,eAAe,CAAC,CAAC;AACjD,OAAO,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,KAAK,CAAC,gBAAgB,CAAC,CAAC;AACrC,OAAO,CAAC,IAAI,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,cAAc,CAAC,CAAC;AAErC,IAAI,OAAO,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;AAChB,GAAG,CAAC,CAAY,UAAoC,EAApC,KAAA,iBAAiB,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,SAAS,CAAC,EAApC,cAAoC,EAApC,IAAoC;IAA/C,IAAM,CAAC,SAAA;IACR,OAAO,CAAC,IAAI,CAAI,OAAO,UAAK,CAAG,CAAC,CAAC;IACjC,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;CACb;AAGD,mBAAmB;AAEnB,uCAAuC;AAEvC,6CAA6C;AAE7C,8EAA8E;AAE9E,eAAe;AACf,0CAA0C;AAE1C,oDAAoD"
}
```

However, when I try to debug under cscript.exe:

```
cscript.exe //x //d loader.js
```

The Visual Studio debugger shows the Javascript, instead of the Typescript.

I know Visual Studio supports source map debugging, and this did work at one point.

There are other answers which suggest providing an absolute path for `sourceRoot` within the `.map` file (in this case, by setting the `sourceRoot` property in the `tsconfig.json`); but this has no effect.

**What steps can I attempt to enable source maps with Visual Studio in this scenario?**

Comment: VS2010 is far too old to have a debugging engine that knows anything about source maps.  You'll have to get closer to 2015.

Comment: When you say this did work at one time, you mean for `cscript.exe` itself or for another `NodeJS` program?

Comment: @TarunLalwani For `cscript.exe`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, posted an answer, that should help your as I have tested many different possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting `inlineSources` to `true` (`inlineSourceMaps` also has to be `true`) in the `tsconfig.json`. This embeds the source in the emitted Javascript file.

Although this greatly increases the size of the Javascript file, this isn't really an issue, since the Javascript is being run locally as opposed to being retrieved from a web server.

Answer (score 2):

So I took a deeper dig at this and see what the issue is exactly. I will talk about pre-requisites that are needed first

**Need .NET Section Installed with Just In Time Debugger**

[image: Installation]

**Need Just-in-time debugging enabled**

[image: JIT]

**Debugging with sourceMap**

I was able to reproduce your issue and I think it may be a bug or edge case not handled properly by VS2017

When you launch script from CMD and chose to open a new window or choose a different project you will see an error saying invalid source map url

[image: Invalid source map url]

This is probably because of some path that VS2017 is taking and it is not same as the script path.

**Fixing the issue**

There are three ways to fix the issue.

**1. Manually fix the full path of sourcemap**

In your `app.js` fix the path of `sourceMappingURL`. And then run `cscript.exe \\X 
\\D app.js`. It will first show the JS file but source map loaded message will be there. After the first step over it will correct the TS file display

[image: First entry]

[image: After stepping over]

**Create a project in VS2017**

Create a project in TypeScript Blank NodeJS VS2017 with your source files and build it. Now when you run the project from command line and choose the same open project, it would work

[image: Choose Open env]

[image: Source Map Loaded]

**Use Inline source map**

This option will make sure that it works from anywhere and even without a project being open in VS2017

Change your `tsconfig.json` to

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es3",
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  }
}
```

This will make sure there whole map is inline and there is no path problem. This time it will open directly in your TS file

[image: Choose new instance]

[image: Works]

Hope this helps your understand why it worked earlier and now. May be your usage was a different and using the edge cases

Comment: Using the `inlineSourceMap` option, Visual Studio prints **Error decoding sourcemap contents.** in the Debug pane.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, That happened to me once, I recreated the maps using `tsc --out app.js app.ts` and it worked that time. Also I would suggest you use the existing open window instead of create new

Comment: I;m curious -- do you need the entire .NET workload enabled? Or just the Just-in-Time debugging option, from Individual Components?

Comment: I think the JIT option should be able to do it

Comment: Apparently not. The **Script** checkbox is not available under **Just In Time Debugging** on the options pages.

Comment: I meant universal windows development and JIt option during installation should do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Visual Studio 2017 solution that contains your files as a the solution items. Have that Visual Studio 2017 solution open and start cscript from a cmd.exe window like you did. You should see a window popping up with the title "Choose Just-In-Time Debugger" which offers you to choose a new instance of Visual Studio, or the existing instance where your solution is loaded. Choose that one. You may see the debugger window hitting your .js file first, but when you step thru the code, it should automatically change to the mapped .ts file, next.

As for the VS project type: You may start with a "Blank Node.js Console Application", remove all what is not needed from that project, and add your stuff then. **You won't use NodeJS of course**, but that project template is tailored to the needs of TypeScript already.

Comment: For me it works just fine. What exactly is the behavior that you see? E.g., are you able to choose the running VS instance after starting "cscript.exe //x //d loader.js"? What happens then?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the way you have configured? I have Visual Studio 2017 with Node JS only module installed and doing this just says the `--inspect-brk` flag is not supported by cscript

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about the steps you take. Where and when exactly does this message ("--inspect-brk flag is not supported by cscript") appear? Are you trying to start debugging from inside VS? My proposal was to start "cscript.exe //x //d loader.js" from a separate cmd.exe box.

Comment: Yes you were right that it works, but there were some edge cases and alternatives. Please look at the detailed answer I have posted.

Comment: Fine. Your answer is certainly more complete. So did you vote down my (basically correct) answer and then used it as the basis to create yours?

Comment: I tried with your solution with just NodeJS part of Visual Studio 2017 installed and that didn't work. With `cscript` or the the direct run approach. That's why the downvote was done. Tried upvoting the answer again after our conversation, but it seems the vote gets locked and I can't upvote until unless you edit your answer. Once you do that I will upvote the same. Sorry for the confusion